# Rails model scoped uniqueness validation unexpectedly skipped in high CPU load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, duplicate-data, model-validation, cpu-load

I realized that Rails scoped validation sometimes skipped unexpectedly which results in duplicated record. As a notice, my server is doing some high CPU tasks which regularly fills 80-100% of 6 CPU cores.

Is my validation setting incorrect, or does Rails has a possibility to insert duplicated records in the case of high load environment?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :message, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}, format: {without: /\s/}
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has a possibility to insert duplicate records, violating the validation.

The reason is because Rails performs two queries for a uniqueness validation - one to check that the value is unique, and then if that succeeds, another to insert the new record.

If another process is doing something and inserts another record *in between* those two queries, you'll end up with duplicate data in the database. I presume high load means the time between the two queries will be longer, increasing the likelihood of this happening.

If you really want to ensure uniqueness, do it with a database-level unique index.

See [Ruby on Rails - Uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426915/ruby-on-rails-uniqueness) for more information (but it's not technically a duplicate question).

Comment: Thank you sevenseacat, so that was an issue. I will go with database-level unique index.